403 Exception trying to read file in Azure Blob
I have a desktop client that calls web service. Among many things, a file in Azure Blob is being accessed (Read) in my code and throws 403 exception in OpenReadAsync function. It happens despite my configuration of Azure AD. I am using the following code, and all the parameters and URL are correct (verified). The strange part is that in another API of my web service it copies the files passed as parameter to Azure Blob just fine and I can see the files in the container in Azure Portal...
`private async Task FetchAndDisplayDocument(string blobUrl)
 {
       using (Log.VerboseCall())
       {
             try
             {
                var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(_azConfig.AzureAD.TenantId, _azConfig.AzureAD.ClientId, _azConfig.AzureAD.ClientSecret);

                // Instantiate a BlobClient which will be used to create or reference a blob
                var blobClient = new BlobClient(new Uri(blobUrl), credential);

                // Download the blob's contents as a stream
                Stream blobStream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync();

                // Assuming you have a method to display this stream content in your right pane
                // and assuming 'this' is a Form or Control that has a method named DisplayDocumentStream
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    DisplayDocumentStream(blobStream);
                });
            }
            catch(RequestFailedException ex)
            {
                Log.Verbose($"{ex.Message}");

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Properties.Settings.Default.AppTitle, 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    return;
                });
             }
        }
}`

So I concluded that the problem is in configuring Azure AD/Entra.
I registered my desktop app and have the following.
I registered and configured the desktop app in Azure AD:

The portal indicates that the certificates and Secrets are current.

Since my web service is in development and runs on local machine, my Redirect includes:
https://localhost:7262 among other things.

Enable mobile and desktop flows: Yes

API Permissions show:


In the "Expose and API" section:



In the App Roles:

Azure Blob:
I have Storage Account of V2 Kind.
In Access Control (IAM): (all these users/admins is me)

These are documents in my container, and I am trying to read the 2nd one:

So, I was banging my head against the wall for 2 days and can't figure out what am I doing wrong...
I hope I did not forget to show any other significant settings and did not expose too much.

Error 403 is not an exception it indicates the results of the HTTP Request is 403 which is forbidden.  The exception is occurring because the body of the HTTP Response is empty when you get the 403 error.  The error is usually caused by the controller code in the server.  The user Role is not allowing the route in the controller to access the data.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Just to clarify: This is a desktop application that executes on my machine against web service that runs on my machine. All API in controller has for now anonymous attribute. The executing code that produces 403 error is the result of the callback received by SignalR. I am not sure that at this point the original anonymous call has something to do with it since it posted task and return way before SignalR callback. As you saw in my code I am calling AzureBlob API directly - I have no API of my own in the controller that routes the call... What role you are referring to in the above posting?

Try adding AllowAnonymous : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-8.0

The whole point of solving this problem is to allow authenticated secure access to the documents stored in Azure Blob - that's why I am trying to replace AllowAnonymous (that I had before) by authenticated and authorized access...Anyway, even with anonymous access it returns 403.

Do google search for "troubleshoot controller azure".  What Group are you using?

You are acquiring the token for the Service Principal (_azConfig.AzureAD.ClientId). Please ensure that you have assigned appropriate RBAC role to this SP.

Gourav, If you are talking about assigning roles to the users (myself in both cases)  then I did so - see screenshot in my post. AFAIK, the assignment of Conditions for each role is optional and not really required... Basically, I login based on AD authentication (getting token and using it in API as Bearer) and upload file to Azure Blob. But one of my operations causes SignalR to return the file URI and I am trying to read it back...in vain...

Here is what I get: Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Service request failed.
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

That’s what I’m saying. You’ve assigned roles to yourself and that’s why you’re able to upload the files. But when reading, you’re using the SP identity. That SP should be assigned Storage Blob Data Reader role in order to read the blob.

Apologies for ignorance, but what is SP identity? (Rhetorical question - reading about it now)

So under Azure AD, I creates a new role AzureBlobReader and gave it a value AzureBlobFileReader. Now I am in my Azure Blob Storage resource in Access Control (IAM) trying to add role assignment. I selected Storage Blob Data Reader and then got to Select dialog for selecting members, however I do not see the role I created earlier (after I waited for 15 min)

Gaurav, you sent me along the right pathway, and I managed to understand and assigned Storage Blob Data Read to my desktop app and found it as a member in the Storage resource roles and assigned it and now the code works. Thank you!

You're using a desktop application, and, in your case, you are authenticating using the Service Principal associated with the App Registration.
In this authentication flow, you don't need any API permissions. You will only need those API permissions for your Web App, and only if the app is using the credential of a signed in user to access Blob Data. Your BlobClient will obtain a token from the Microsoft and use it to access the Blob Storage Service. It's not calling the Graph API.

In Access Control (IAM): (all these users/admins is me)

I suspect you've assigned your personal admin account these IAM roles. You need to assign them to the service principal.
In Portal -> Your Blob Storage Account -> IAM:

Select + Add -> Add role assignment.
Click on the Role drop down
Search and select "Storage Blob Data Reader" or "Storage Blob Data Contributer".
In the Assign access to dropdown, search and select your service principal. You can use your clientId or App Registration name.
Save role assignment

This should allow your desktop app to read blobs in all containers of the storage account you added the role assignment to.
NOTE: I did once have a strange scenario where Storage Account Role Assignments were not being inherited by one particular container, and I had to create the role assignment at the container level instead.

Jamie, thank you for your response, but I have to be fair Gaurav with his comment lead me to the solution first.

That's fine. I was probably writing this answer while you were having a discussion. I didn't see it :)
